# DB is updated but api is not showing any content in Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am building one website using Flask. The app.py, html template and db(postgresql) data is shown below.On hitting the URL http://127.0.0.1:5000/ we can enter the username and email. http://127.0.0.1:5000/users will show the content which is updated in db here it is Mak mak@mk.com.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,request, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 
'postgres://postgres:123@localhost/sample'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80))
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique = True)
    def __init__(self, username, email):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' %self.username
@app.route('/')
#def index():
def index():
    return render_template('add_user.html')
@app.route('/post_user', methods=['POST'])
def post_user():
    user = User(request.form['username'], request.form['email'])
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
@app.route('/users')
def get_users():
    users = User.query.all()
    return render_template('get_user.html', user = users)
@app.route('/homepage')
def display_homepage():
    return 'Display homepage'
if __name__ =='__main__':
    app.run()
```

get_user.html

```
{% for singleuser in users %}
  <ul>
<li>singleuser.username</li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Sql Schema details
           1    "Mak"   "mak@mak.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `get_users ()`, there's a typo in the return statement

```
return render_template('get_user.html', users = users)
```